# ConTeXt: Font change shifts column content

Tags: fonts, spacing, lists, two-column, context-mkiv

## Background

I would like to place balanced itemized lists inside a two-column layout.

## Problem

Changing the font affects the balanced layout; the fonts are:

- [Chivo](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Chivo)
- [Gentium Basic](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Gentium+Basic)

## Code

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
\starttypescript [sans] [TestSans]
  \definefontsynonym [Sans]           [name:chivoregular]
  \definefontsynonym [SansBold]       [name:chivoblack]
  \definefontsynonym [SansItalic]     [name:chivoitalic]
  \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [name:chivoblackitalic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [TestSerif]
  \definefontsynonym [Serif]           [name:gentiumbasic]
  \definefontsynonym [SerifBold]       [name:gentiumbasicbold]
  \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic]     [name:gentiumbasicitalic]
  \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [name:gentiumbasicbolditalic]
\stoptypescript

\definetypeface [TestFont] [rm] [serif] [TestSerif] [default]
\definetypeface [TestFont] [ss] [sans]  [TestSans]  [default]

\usetypescript[TestFont][ec]
%\setupbodyfont[TestFont]

\define[1]\IngredientName{\expanded{\index{#1+\namedstructurevariable{section}{title}}{#1}}}

\define[1]\IngredientUnit{#1}

\define[1]\IngredientMeasure{
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    %
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}

\define[3]\ingredient{\startitem\IngredientUnit{#1}\IngredientMeasure{#2}\IngredientName{#3}\stopitem}

\definestartstop[TestIngredientGroup]
\defineitemgroup[TestIngredient]

\setupstartstop[TestIngredientGroup][
  before={\startmixedcolumns[balance=yes,grid=,]},
  after={\stopmixedcolumns},
]

\defineitemgroup[TestIngredient]
\setupitemgroup[TestIngredient][each][packed][
  width=\zeropoint,
  %before={\vskip-.5em},
  %after={\vskip.5em},
  symbol=,
]

\setuphead[subsection][
  number=no,
  %before={\testcolumn[2]},
  %after={\empty},
  style=\ss,
]

\starttext

\startTestIngredientGroup
\startsubsection[title={Main Ingredients},]
\startTestIngredient
  \ingredient{1}{}{egg}\ingredient{1}{}{avocado}
  %\ingredient{1}{pkg}{applewood-smoked bacon}\ingredient{1}{}{onion}\ingredient{2}{tbsp}{flour}\ingredient{2\vfrac{1}{2}}{cup}{fish stock}\ingredient{1}{}{potato}\ingredient{\vfrac{1}{2}}{tsp}{cayenne pepper}\ingredient{\vfrac{1}{2}}{tsp}{nutmeg}\ingredient{1\vfrac{1}{2}\emdash{}2}{cup}{milk}\ingredient{\vfrac{1}{2}}{cup}{cream}\ingredient{1}{pinch}{salt}\ingredient{1}{pinch}{pepper}\ingredient{1}{tsp}{lime juice}
\stopTestIngredient
\stopsubsection
\stopTestIngredientGroup

\stoptext
```

The result initially looks satisfactory; the problem occurs when trying to adjust the whitespace, the font, or both.

## Reproduce Problem

Apply the fonts by uncommenting: `%\setupbodyfont[TestFont]`, which produces:

[image: Font Change]

The columnar content has shifted from the left column to the right column. This can be addressed by uncommenting: `%before={\vskip-.5em},`, which produces:

[image: Vertical Skip]

This works for two lines, but enabling `%\ingredient{1}{pkg}{applewood-smoked bacon}...` results in missing text:

[image: Missing Text]

Several lines have disappeared completely, regardless of font. The
lines can be made visible again, but then the situation reverts to
shifting the content from the left column to the right column when
there are only a couple of items in the list.

I've tried:

- setting `grid=strut`, `grid=`, `grid=verytolerant`, and `grid=stretch`;
- adding `[intro]` to the lists;
- using `\testcolumn[3]` to prevent orphaned subsection titles; and
- coding various combinations of `\vskip` and `\empty` on `before` and `after` attributes for both the itemized list and the subsection title.

## Question

Using a two-column setup, is there a way to reduce the amount of space?

The best result I can achieve without losing any content contains extraneous whitespace:

[image: Extraneous Whitespace]

What I would like to achieve resembles:

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `\vskip` in favour of `\blank[small]`.

For example, on the lists use:

```
before={\blank[small]},
after={\blank[small]},
```

And on the subsection title use:

```
\setuphead[subsection][
  % Avoid orphaned titles.
  before={\testcolumn[3]},
  after={\blank[small]},
]
```

This produces the desired result.

See also: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/blank